# how to run .sh file in Ubuntu using installScript

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04, installshield, installscript

I am creating an installation using InstallShield 2018 in windows 10. I need to execute a script file (.sh) in Ubuntu from a function in Installscript. I tried the following but it did not work:

```
szCmdPath = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\Ubuntu.exe";
szCmdLine = ". /mnt/d/test.sh";
LaunchAppAndWait( szCmdPath, szCmdLine, WAIT);
```

However I can execute the exact same file in Ubuntu Terminal and it works great. I did turn on Window sub system for Linux and install Ubuntu on windows. Why is this happening? Why can I run cmd.exe from installscript but not Ubuntu? 
Thank you in advance.

EDIT 1: if I pass an empty string as parameter, Ubuntu is start and waits for my input commands. But when I pass the path to my script file, nothing happened except a flash of the terminal console before my installation goes on running.

Answer (score 0):

From [my reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config), `wsl` and `ubuntu` differ slightly. It looks like `wsl` is a bit magical and occasionally similar to `bash -c` or `ubuntu -c`, whereas you can consider `Ubuntu.exe` as somewhat equivalent to `/bin/bash`.

If you try to run `/bin/bash . /mnt/d/test.sh` from a bash prompt, things don't go well. So the correct approach will depend on the contents of your script and what you need to happen. I think one of the following options are the most likely:

- remove `.` from your command; instead run `...\Ubuntu.exe` `/mnt/d/test.sh`
- add `-c` to your command; instead run `...\Ubuntu.exe` `-c . /mnt/d/test.sh`

Note that `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Ubuntu.exe` is a special file (zero bytes), so it's also plausible that it needs some special handling. For instance, maybe it requires a 64-bit caller. If that's the case, you may need to wrap it in a call through a 64-bit cmd prompt. My quick tests don't show this as likely, however, so I think it will work without this extra indirection.